# Парсинг пользователей из каналов\чатов в Telegram

Tags: php, python, json, telegram

Стала задача спарсить пользователей с определенного канала\чата, что бы потом "пригласить" в свой канал. Гуглил - подобной реализации не встречал как в рунете, так и на англоязычных ресурсах. Документация Телеграма не помогла.
п.с. Предпочтительно использовать Python, но не гнушаюсь и других языков.
Жду ссылок, или поделитесь своими наработками и\или примерами реализации.

Comment: К сожалению, это не сайт фрилансеров, поэтому от вас ожидаются попытки решения вашего вопроса, которые будут в вопросе, чтобы сообщество помогло :) А так, если парсить сайты, используются панели инструментов (на странице правой кнопкой и выбор "Inspector" или что-то подобное) и просмотр структуры страницы, после используя: регулярные выражения (плохой вариант), xpath-запрос / css-селекторы или работу с dom и вытаскиваются нужные данные. Если же у сайта есть api, то, конечно используйте api.

Comment: Еще некоторые сайты использую ajax-запросы, которые через те инструменты браузера можно увидеть и повторять, такие запросы могут вернуть не html, а json или xml, с которыми проще иметь дела. Удачи :)

Comment: [официальная документация](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34567920/in-python-telegram-bot-how-to-get-all-participants-of-the-group) не помогла, точно?

Comment: думаю что это невозможно, телеграм присваивает уникальный id, используя который возможно общение с пользователем. id выдается только тогда когда пользователь что нибудь отпишет вашему боту

Comment: Вот тут [Парсинг групп в telegram](http://ebot.one/wiki/index.php/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D1%8B) через бота, может подойдет и для канала, 100% уверенности нет, но попробуй